# Installing Sqlite3 for Ruby (Mac OSX 10.5.8)

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, sqlite3-ruby

I am following this guide ATM - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

When trying to create a database, I got:

Morgans-Computer:blog Morgan$ rake db:create
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

When I try to run 'bundle install', I get more errors:

Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions /Users/Morgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

```
    /Users/Morgan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

I have tried to install the Ruby Gem Sqlite3 (http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby) but it continues to fail. I found another post on here saying that I need to install C because that is what the compiler is written in? Wasn't sure exactly what that meant, or how I go about doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't already have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, I would set that up first. It's a nice package manager and allows you to install things like sqlite with `brew install sqlite`.

To install brew you'll need xcode installed. If you don't already have that you'll probably need the cd that came with you system, or you can download from [apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). On the latest OS, you can install it from the App Store which is nice (This might work for you too).

If you have mysql and would prefer to use that instead and sidestep the sqlite issue you can generate your rails project as such.

```
rails new my_new_project -d mysql
```

Comment: omg...I have been looking for that answer for hours. Thanks! Will test it out and let you know (I have homebrew installed already)....update: that worked!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you install the sqlite adapter gem, it has to compile code. To compile the code, it needs access to the sqlite development libraries.

This [Rails on Mac OS X tutorial](http://railsonosx.com/) explains how to do it. Here is the most immediately relevant part:

```
   sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local #make sure we have correct permissions to install sqlite
   brew install sqlite
   gem install sqlite3
```

Comment: I have homebrew installed. Yea, I have seen the posts for ubntu, but that doesn't seem to work in mac?

Comment: Certainly that doesn't work on OSX, it doesn't use apt as a package manager.

Comment: yea, once I got brew install sqlite, I got it going from there. Thanks again for the help, the hair that I have left will remain on my head...

Comment: Good to hear. I'd give Blake Taylor best answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you'll probably want to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). You will also likely need some other packages for `sqlite3`, which you should be able to get through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (ports: `sqlite3` + `rb19-sqlite3`).

If you already have Xcode installed, go to the [MacPorts Install page](https://www.macports.org/install.php), download and install the provided `.dmg`. Then you should be able to run this from the console to install the necessary packages:

```
sudo port install sqlite3 rb19-sqlite3
```

You can also use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), as others have suggested.

Comment: Yea, I have Xcode installed. How do I install the other packages?